# Inject reference to async service - drawbacks

Tags: java, gwt, memory, singleton

If in my GWT UI component I am using @Inject for reference of my CoolServiceAsync interface - will that create separate instance of the "implementation" of that service from GWT bindings? Or it is singleton and same instance of JavaScript object will be shared among all components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must probably specify what you use for IoC in GWT. I assume you use google-gin. Unless you specify a binding as singleton, it will be created with help of [GWT.create()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#create%28java.lang.Class%29), because of the deferred binding. [GWT.create()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#create%28java.lang.Class%29) always returns new instance.

Comment: So I need specify @Singleton on interface - and that will do the trick?

Comment: I think you are able to test it by yourself.

Comment: keeping in mind that objects in GWT are not really Java objects and don't have associated unique id it could be hard.

Comment: @jdevelop, can you please explain why? a == b should give you a boolean answer. In the end, have a Provider and call get() two times. Compare results. Profit!